# Adding elements to new array Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, fizzbuzz

So initially I'm just playing around with the ole 'FizzBuzz' challenge. For those that may be unaware of what this challenge is, allow me to explain. The idea is to print out numbers `1..100` if the number is divisible by `3`, it prints `Fizz` instead of `3`; if the number is divisible by `5`, it prints `Buzz`; And if number is divisible by both, it prints `FizzBuzz`. This is how I performed the challenge:

```
def super_fizzbuzz(array)  
  array.each do |element|
    if element % 15 == 0 
      puts 'FizzBuzz'
    elsif element % 5 == 0
      puts 'Buzz'
    elsif element % 3 == 0
       puts "Fizz"
    else 
       puts element
    end
  end
end
```

This will work as intended. What I am trying to do is have it so the user can put in an array of integers `super_fizzbuzz([3,10,15,19])` And have it return the array with the appropriate word replacing the number: `[Fizz, Buzz, FizzBuzz, 19]`. However, I can't seem to perform this. I have tried the following below, but it only adds the first answer to the array..

```
super_array = []
array.each do |element|
  if element % 15 == 0 
    super_array[element] << 'FizzBuzz'
  elsif element % 5 == 0
    super_array << 'Buzz'
  elsif element % 3 == 0
    super_array << "Fizz"
  else
    super_array << element
  end

  return super_array
end
```

My thought process was to create a new array and if the element was divisible by by one or both of the numbers it would place it in the new array, and if it wasn't it would just place the element in the array. What happens when I run it though is that it will just return an array with `Fizz`. If I run the first code and place the numbers in an array it returns:

```
Fizz
Buzz
FizzBuzz
19
[3, 10, 15, 19]
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`return super_array`

this statement says "stop everything you are doing and return this value right now"

Therefore the first time through the array, you will get one answer... and then hit this result, and then return this array result without continuing through the rest of the array.

probably what you want is to only return the new "super_array" value after you've gone through the whole original array... so I'd move it to just outside the loop eg:

```
super_array = []
array.each do |element|
  if element % 15 == 0 
    super_array[element] << 'FizzBuzz'
  elsif element % 5 == 0
    super_array << 'Buzz'
  elsif element % 3 == 0
    super_array << "Fizz"
  else
    super_array << element
  end
end
return super_array # only return once through the whole array
```

Comment: I see. I have removed `return super_array`. As of now, the program is just returning the very array that I put in. `[3,10,15,19]`. Still working on it, good catch though!

Comment: Awesome! Just refreshed and applied what you had said, this worked perfectly! Thank you for your response.

Comment: Have a look at my updated suggestion - you do need to return super_array - just after the loop - haha - SNAP we're both typing at the same time ;)

Comment: Switching to `map` would be even better.

Answer (score 1):

As @mu is too short mentioned, this is a prime case for using `Enumerable`'s `map` method:

```
nums = [3, 15, 29, 42, 18, 63, 10]

def to_fizzbuzz
  if self % 15 == 0
    "FizzBuzz"
  elsif self % 5 == 0
    "Buzz"
  elsif self % 3 == 0
    "Fizz"
  else
    self
  end
end

nums.map(&:to_fizzbuzz) #=> ["Fizz", "FizzBuzz", 29, "Fizz", "Fizz", "Buzz"]
```